# Is there a way to copy a specific sheet from one workbook to a specific (and different) folder as its own stand alone sheet in google?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am not a developer or coder, just trying to learn and automate tasks*.  This is what I have so far:

function saveAsSpreadsheet() {

var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var sheet = source.getSheets()[6];

var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getSheetId()).makeCopy("desired file name", destFolder);

} //END function saveAsSpreadsheet

I get the error "Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp."

Any tweaks that might make this work?

Comment: What's a workbook? What's a folder?What's a stand alone sheet? Learn how to format your code.

Comment: I should add that I am not a developer or coder by trade. I work in finance but am trying to find a better solution to a task. Thanks for the helpful comment though.

Answer (score 0):

### Issues:

- You are trying to use the sheet id instead of spreadsheet id in [DriveApp.getFileById(file id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid).
- Using [makeCopy(name, destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file?hl=en#makecopyname,-destination) will copy the content of the whole spreadsheet.

**Try this:**

```
function saveAsSpreadsheet() {
  var folderId = "id";
  var fileName = "new File";
  var file = Drive.Files.insert({title: fileName, mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, parents: [{id: folderId}]});
  var newFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.id);
  
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = source.getSheets()[0];
  var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
  sheet.copyTo(newFile).setName(sheetName);
}
```

**Note:** *Make sure to add Drive API to the project **Services**. See [how to add Services in Apps Script.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services)*

### Example:

**Source file:**

[image: source]

**Destination:**

[image]

**Reference:**

- [Drive.Files.insert()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert)

Comment: Thank you! I’ll give this a go.